# Different functions definition in F#

Tags: f#

Newby question f# related,

What is the difference between this definitions in f# ?

```
module s
    let log p =
        printfn "expression is %A" p

    let loggedWorkflow =
        let x = 42
        log x
        let y = 43
        log y
        let z = x + y
        log z
        z

s.loggedWorkflow
```

and this one

```
module s
    let log p =
        printfn "expression is %A" p

    let loggedWorkflow() =
        let x = 42
        log x
        let y = 43
        log y
        let z = x + y
        log z
        z

s.loggedWorkflow()
```

The first one does not call the inner log, only returns z value
Why it works this way?

Thanks :)

I take this sample from
http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/computation-expressions-intro/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`let loggedWorkflow = ...` is defining a *value*. The body is evaluated as soon as the definition is reached (typically when the module `s` is loaded), and the value of `loggedWorkflow` is remembered as the result of evaluating the body, and returned every time someone evaluates `s.loggedWorkflow`.

`let loggedWorkflow() = ...` is defining a *function* that takes a single argument of type `unit` - the only value of this type is `()`, also typically pronounced "unit". The body doesn't get evaluated straight away, but only when the function is actually called. Each time it is called by actually passing an argument of type `unit`, e.g. with `s.loggedWorkflow()`,  the body is evaluated and the resulting value returned.